# Unable to style Django Default Login Form with Bootstrap

Tags: python, html, css, django, docker

When I try to style Django default login template with a bootstrap in a custom forms.py file it doesn't work. There are no error but I still see the default un-styled login form.

In other words, LoginView doesn't appear to be using the AuthenticationForm at all.

Login.html

```
<body>
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth import views

from myProject.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [

    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(),{'template_name':'registration/login.html','authentication_form':LoginForm}),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'),{'authentication_form':LoginForm})
```

I've tried several things including using different syntax for 'accounts/login/' and 'login/' paths above as I thought that could have been my problem but it hasn't made any difference.

What I expect to get with the bootstrap
[image: What I expect to get with the bootstrap]

What I still get
[image: What I still get]

I'm running this in Docker so whenever I make a change I do:

```
Docker compose down
Docker compose up
```

and I see the changes once the server restarts.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Try to rewrite your code as following:

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**
...

```
path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view('template_name':'registration/login.html','form_class':LoginForm}),
path('login/', LoginView.as_view('template_name':'registration/login.html','form_class':LoginForm}),
```

The rest seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can override the attrs and use the way AuthenticationForm defines the widgets

```
class UserAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["username"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Email Address"})
    self.fields["password"].widget.attrs.update({"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Password"})
```